# Cordova - how to save image in a specific album

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have a code that take a picture:

```
 $scope.takePhoto = function () {
    var options = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 400,
      targetHeight: 400,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
  };

  $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

          setTimeout(function(){ 
                    $scope.$apply(function () {                     
                        $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;                  
                      },1000);
                });
      }, function(err) {
          // An error occured. Show a message to the user
      });
}
```

I want that the image will save in album named "Test". how can I do it?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If you can do it. there is a documentation on github and it has a lot of things but nothing about changing the location of saveToPhotoAlbum option.
You are going to probably have to ask the developers and hope for a response or edit the java files yourself

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

Also, do not use DATA_URL on destinationType. It's extremely slow, use FILE_URI. See here

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#camera-getPicture-examples

What I was able to find from a quick look in Java files. Go to
yourProject/plugins/cordova-plugin-camera/src/android. Open the CameraLauncher.java and on line 578 you have

`File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`

Try changing that to DIRECTORY_TEST

Comment: Now, with the original code (camera plugin) when I set saveToPhotoAlbum its save the photo in a new album named "Pictures". I should find where "Pictures" appear in the code or its save in this album automatically?

Comment: Did you actually read what I wrote? Short answer, yes.
"What I was able to find from a quick look in Java files. Go to yourProject/plugins/cordova-plugin-camera/src/android. Open the CameraLauncher.java and on line 578 you have

File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

Try changing that to DIRECTORY_TEST"

Comment: DIRECTORY_TEST" ? Are you mean DIRECTORY_"TEST" or something?

Comment: No quotes arround the "TEST" just DIRECTORY_TEST. 

See this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)